# When will boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(remoteHost) throw an exception

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Will the following statement throw an exception if and only if my `remoteHost` variable is not a string in decimal dot format?

```
boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(remoteHost)
```

I really want to check the validity of my `remoteHost` variable in my scheme rather then runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: [The documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address/from_string.html) says nothing about exceptions. It seems that if you want to check for errors, you need to use the two-argument overload of the function, to get an error code.

Comment: The single argument function calls the two-argument function. I followed the documentation for sometime and then stopped. I was hoping for an expert that already knew the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the two argument version in `address.ipp` to the versions in `address_v6.ipp` and `address_v4.ipp` you'll see that they both call `boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::inet_pton` defined in [socket_ops.ipp](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp) starting at line 2029.

It's a long function, so I'll leave it up to you to see precisely what it requires.